# Not able to access logs from Web App when log aggregation is enabled

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running my Spark Application on YARN(2.6). In order to aggregate logs I have set `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` as `true`

Fetching the log using  `yarn logs -applicationId application_1434563132203_0001` works without any issues. I was able to retrieve logs of 3 Containers which ran as part of the Application

```
mountain@mountain:~/sbook$ yarn logs -applicationId application_1434563132203_0001 | grep Container:
Container: container_1434563132203_0001_01_000003 on mountain_38524
Container: container_1434563132203_0001_01_000001 on mountain_38524
Container: container_1434563132203_0001_01_000002 on mountain_38524
```

When I tried to access the same logs from Web App I am getting this following error :

I go to Resource Manager Web App(localhost:8088),

[image]

After clicking the link I go to,

[image]

When I click the `logs` link I am getting this error message in the new page,

[image]

Do I need to enable any configuration in order to access my logs from Web App?